# Why the virtual environment runs system Python 2.7 instead of virtual Python 3.6

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, interpreter

I've created a Django project in a virtual environment, and `venv` was activated by PyCharm automatically, as usual. Everything was fine, but when I placed my project into another folder, Project Interpreter settings were corrupted because of old interpreter path.
So now, when I provide a new path for the interpreter (and, of course, with activated `venv`), `python` runs from my base system location of version 2.7, not from venv.

**Check this:**

```
archeski@archeski-Inspiron-5558:~/Source/ecom/ecom$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) archeski@archeski-Inspiron-5558:~/Source/ecom/ecom$ python --version
Python 2.7.15rc1
(venv) archeski@archeski-Inspiron-5558:~/Source/ecom/ecom$ python -c "import sys; print sys.executable"
/usr/bin/python
```

[image]

[image]

**The same thing happened about a half year ago on Windows 10, and the solution was only to create a project in PyCharm from scratch  and then move all the source, db and etc.
Now, I'm running on Ubuntu 18.04**

Comment: Can you add edit Pycharm environment and print screen it and put here  ?

Comment: @A'zamMamatmurodov done.

Comment: I think it only shows "Python 3.6", try to use Pycharm terminal and type "python --version" in your terminal

Comment: @A'zamMamatmurodov I've done this before, see the question details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000062344-How-to-move-complete-Python-environment-to-new-PC-with-virtual-environment
>
> Normally environments are tied to a specific path. That means that you
> cannot move an environment around or copy it to another computer. You
> can fix up an environment to make it relocatable with the command:
>
> $ virtualenv --relocatable ENV
>
> The --relocatable option currently has a number of issues, and is not
> guaranteed to work in all circumstances. It is possible that the
> option will be deprecated in a future version of virtualenv